SSD patriot BURST REPAIR
Hello im looking for this small SOT-23-5 IC if anyone know the part number its from a Ssd board of the Patriot burst 

It appears to be G5728B, a 1.4 MHz Synchronous Buck Converter IC from GMT (Global Mixed-Mode Technology).
The pinout shown in the datasheet and the components shown on the PCB photo match.

yea probably its this you have said and thank you, i have ordered this already TLV62569DBVR its similar? https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv62569.pdf?ts=1722484287261

@tojirok they look quite similar. Same FB reference voltage, pretty much the same operating frequency. Even the typical application schematic (values) the same.
